# Whenever i disable or hide submit button the form doesnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Whenever i disable or hide submit button the form doesnt submit:

```
<form action="leads_add.php" method="post" name="leads_form" id="leads_form">

<input type="submit" name="saveforlaterbutton" value="Save for later" class=" btn btn-primary" id="saveforlaterbutton" >

   <script>
    $("#leads_form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#saveforlaterbutton").hide();
    });
    </script>
```

I also tried:

```
<input type="submit" name="saveforlaterbutton" value="Save for later" class=" btn btn-primary" id="saveforlaterbutton" onclick="this.disabled=true;return false;">
```

If i click the button, it disables/hides the button but then nothing happens;the form doesnt submit

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're canceling the submit action. Remove this line:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit you need to remove :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the form from being submitted.

and also you need **not** put `onclick="this.disabled=true;return false;"`.

The return false is not required.

If you really want you can do `onclick="this.disabled=true;"`

Answer (score 0):

i removed but it didnt work

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This is what worked for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#leads_form').on('submit', function(evt) {
    $('#saveforlaterbutton').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```